# Oracle SQL - Combine results from two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am seeking to combine the results of two columns, and view it in a single column:

```
select description1, description2 from daclog where description2 is not null;
```

results two registry:

1st row:

DESCRIPTION1

```
Initialization scans sent to RTU 1, 32 bit mask: 0x00000048. Initialization mask bits are as follows: B0 - status dump, B1 - analog dump B2 - accumulator dump, B3 - Group Data Dump, B4 - accumulat
```

(here begin DESCRIPTION2)

> ,or freeze, B5 - power fail reset, B6 - time sync.

2nd row:

DESCRIPTION1

```
Initialization scans sent to RTU 1, 32 bit mask: 0x00000048. Initialization mask bits are as follows: B0 - status dump, B1 - analog dump B2 - accumulator dump, B3 - Group Data Dump, B4 - accumulat
```

(here begin DESCRIPTION2)

> ,or freeze, B5 - power fail reset, B6 - time sync.

Then I need the value of description1 and description2, on the same column.

It is possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Like this? `select description1 || description2 from daclog where description2 is not null;`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two columns into one by using `||` operator.

```
select description1 || description2 as description from daclog where description2 is not null;
```

If you would like to use some substrings from each of the descriptions, you can use String functions and then combine the results. `FNC(description1) || FNC(descriptions2)` where FNC might be a function to return the desired substring of your columns.